# loadmovie into _level0, all others _levels will reset?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a simple swf file, it load three movie movie(swf) in to 3 different _level :

```
loadMovieNum("test1.swf", 0);
loadMovieNum("test2.swf", 1);
loadMovieNum("test3.swf", 2);
```

test2.swf just have a button with script :

```
on (release) {
 loadMovieNum("test2.swf",0);
}
```

test3.swf have a button with script :

```
on (release) {
 loadMovieNum("test3.swf",1);
}
```

The problem is when I press **test3.swf**'s button,it load **test3.swf** into `_level1`,others `_level` still remain,but when I press **test2.swf**'s button it load **test2.swf** into `_level0`,and others `_level` dissappear.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, loading into level 0 effectively replaces the contents of your main SWF with the loaded SWF. Just start at level 1 and all is golden.